# Assign empty system variable using setx

Tags: batch-file

I need a system variable and assign an empty string value to it. I've tried

```
setx samplepassword ""
```

But upon `echo %samplepassword%` , what should be an empty string is instead `%samplepassword%`. Now I found this in the docs

> Setting value of "" (empty quotes) will appear to delete the variable
>   - it's not shown by SET but the variable name will remain in the registry.

http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html

How can I assign an empty system variable using setx?

Update:
I have checked the environment variables via the Windows GUI: `Control Panel | System | Advanced | Environment Variables` and saw that the `DB_PASSWORD` was indeed initialized with an empty string value. But why does executing `echo %samplepassword%` give me the above output? I have opened a new instance of cmd to be precise.

Comment: Seems right to me. I doubt your db password variable is truly empty.  It is probably using some character that it cannot display.

Comment: I actually tried `setx samplepassword "\"` then `echo %samplepassword%` showed me `\ `. I then tried `setx samplepassword ""` to see if the same system behaviour will occur, and it did.

Comment: I think you have a misconception here. There is no way to assign an "empty string" to an environment (Batch) variable. The command `set "samplepassword="` _deletes_ the variable, so `echo "%samplepassword%"` just show `""`. You don't need `setx` command to do that, nor `setx` can modify this behavior.

Comment: I'm sorry @Aacini, but is the question not clear? I am confused with your comment.

Comment: @EduardDaduya Aacini's comment is right. Even if you set an empty system variable, in the environment this variable can't exist, as it's empty. When you try to echo an empty variable on the **command line** then the complete expression will be unchanged, therefore you get `%samplepassword%`. In a batch file it works as expected when you try to `echo the password is %samplepassword%`

Comment: I see, @Aacini did mention that 'There is no way to assign an "empty string" to an environment (Batch) variable.' Thank you for this clarification.

Comment: Thank you for this information. Please tell if this questions needs to be deleted or should I leave this here for future reference.

Comment: The comments above are important for many. Do not delete the question, unless its a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I think you have a misconception here. There is no way to assign an
>   "empty string" to an environment (Batch) variable. The command set
>   "samplepassword=" deletes the variable, so echo "%samplepassword%"
>   just show "". You don't need setx command to do that, nor setx can
>   modify this behavior. – [Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini) Aug 9 at 4:39

TL;DR: *Technically it is not possible to create an empty variable in the environment.  – [Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini)*

Answer (score 5):

Technically you can create an empty environment variable, but not with `setx`.

Run that as administrator

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"  /v TESTENV /d ""
```

the registry key is added:

[image]

it even shows in environment variables system panel

[image]

But not in the list when invoking `set`

So even if it is possible, it is rather useless. However it could fool some programs testing if the env. variable exists by checking if registry key exists. So it could even be counter-productive and source of confusion.

Comment: Well, technically it is not possible to create an empty variable **in the environment**. Your example show that is possible to create an empty variable **in the registry**, that is an entirely different thing! Your conclusion is useful: a program should never check for an _environment variable_ reviewing _the registry_.

Comment: It's far from "useless". I used empty env vars all the time in Unix. Extremely useful - just broken in dear old Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem getting a file name with or without a suffix. You can work around this with a string prefix and string extraction (see [here](https://superuser.com/q/228794/1120746)), e.g.

- not empty string:

  ```
  set COUNT=two
  set SUFFIX=?s
  echo %COUNT% thing%SUFFIX:~1%
  ```

  gives `two things`
- empty string

  ```
  set COUNT=one
  set SUFFIX=?
  echo %COUNT% thing%SUFFIX:~1%
  ```

  gives `one thing`

With the `%SUFFIX:~1%` you dismiss the string prefix (in this example `?`) and get the rest of the string. This rest can be empty.

Answer (score 2):

Worth pointing out that Windows does not support blank/empty values for environment values.

Try and define a new environment variable from `Settings > System > About > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables`. If no value is entered (see image below) then the `OK` button is disabled.

[image: Cannot define environment variable with blank value]

Or try and create the environment variable in code (see C# example below) with a blank (or `null`) value...and the environment variable is deleted!

```
// If not existing, the environment variable does NOT get defined
// If it exists, the environment variable is deleted
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(
    "TestBlank",
    string.Empty, // Or "null"
    EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
```

The minimum length of environment variable values is 1. The maximum length is (2^16 - 2) = 32766 (or `Int16.MaxValue - 1` in C#). You must do this in code, though, as the Windows GUI limits you to 2047 characters. Why these limits? Not sure, probably historical (aka "lost in the mists of time").

So if you use `set` or `setx` with a blank value, you are actually deleting the variable (which is likely not your intention).